# What is difference between delta QP and simple QP?

Tags: x264, hevc, libx265, video-compression

In context of video coding (especially HEVC), what is difference between delta qp and simple qp values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by Simple QP? 
In HEVC(or any video codec for that matter), QP can be varied at various levels(frame level, slice level or block level). Delta QP comes into picture when QPs are varied at block level. For each block a differential QP is coded which is equal to (absolute QP of the current block - previously encoded QP) and this is called Delta QP. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks that was a very precise explanation. Still I can't understand "If I want to assign more than one QP by varying QP at block levels, say I want to encode half coding units by different QP and half coding units by different QP in a single frame" How can I do this? I know now I have to do something with delta QP.

Comment: If you are using HM reference encoder, You can set the parameter "LCULevelRateControl" to 1 in the config file. This will assign different QP to different LCU based on its complexity. Similar controls will be present in x265 encoder as well(check for --rd-refine and --aq-mode parameter). If you want to force particular QP for some blocks, then you will have to make changes in the encoder.